# Unable to convert Hyphen to UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm reading some text that I got from Wikipedia.
The text contains hyphen like in this String: **"Australia for the [[2011–12 NBL season]]"**

I'm trying to do is to convert the text to utf-8, using this code:

```
String myStr = "Australia for the [[2011–12 NBL season]]";
new String(myStr.getBytes(), "utf-8");
```

The result is:

```
Australia for the [[2011�12 NBL season]]
```

The problem is that the hyphen is not being mapped correctly.

The hyphen value in bytes is [-106] (I have no idea what to do with it...)

Do you know how to convert it to a hyphen that utf-8 encoding recognizes?

I would be happy to replace other special characters as well by some general code, but also specific "hyphens" replacement code will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem code point is [U+2013 EN DASH](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2000.pdf) which can be represented with the escape `\u2013`.

Try replacing the string with "2011\u201312". If this works then there is a mismatch between your editor character encoding and the one [the compiler](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_sourcefiles) is using.

Otherwise, the problem is with the transcoding operation from string to whatever device you are writing to. Anywhere where you convert from bytes to chars or chars to bytes is a potential point of corruption when the wrong encoding is used; this can include `System.out`.

---

Note: Java strings are always UTF-16.

```
new String(myStr.getBytes(), "utf-8");
```

This code takes UTF-16, converts it to the platform encoding, which might be anything, then pretends its UTF-8 and converts it back to UTF-16. At best, the platform encoding is UTF-8 and this is a no-op; otherwise it will just corrupt the data.

This is how you create UTF-8 in Java:

```
byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // Java 7
```

You can read more [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is because the source code (**editor**) is maybe in Windows-1252 (extended Latin-1), and it is compiled with another encoding UTF-8 (**compiler**). These two encodings must be the same, or use in the source: "\u00AD", the ASCII representation of the hyphen.